# How to get the CheckBox is checked or unChecked at specific item in ListView in android

Tags: android-layout

I am building an Student Management System in android.
[Image show the basic Layout of the Main Activity.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZInT1.png)
Every ListView Item Consist of 2 TextViews(Name and Phone Number) and 1 CheckBox. Data is showing on listview is coming from database using SimpleCursorAdapter.Only Name and Phone Number is coming from database.

### Problem is: ##

When I click on SaveAndSend button i am unable to get the checkbox  is checked or unchecked at specific position.

---

code for row.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:padding="6dip">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Name: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="Phone: "
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="TextView" />


    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:tag="usman"
        android:text="Present" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Code for main.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="Save And Send"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:onClick="SaveAndSend"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/saveAndSend" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That code works for me.
OnClick of ListView Item I add the specific column index data into ArrayList.
Onclick of ListView item if checkbox is checked then it add data into ArrayList and remove if CheckBox is unChecked.

---

```
    ArrayList<String> SelectedItem=new ArrayList<>();
       listView = (ListView) findViewById(listView1);
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view, int position, long id) {
                CheckBox checkBox= (CheckBox) listView.getAdapter().getView(position, view, null).findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
                if (checkBox.isChecked()) {
                    checkBox.setChecked(false);
                } else {
                    checkBox.setChecked(true);
                }
                Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String item= cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("contact"));//contact is column name
                if (SelectItems.contains(item)) {
                    SelectItems.remove(item);

                } else {
                    SelectItems.add(item);     
                }
            }
        });
```

---

OnClick of SaveAndSend Button we get the checked item from ArrayList which we added when we click on ListView Item....

```
public void SaveAndSend(View view) {
        for (String item : SelectItems) {
            SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
            sms.sendTextMessage(item, null, "Your Child is  Present on That Date " + new Date(), null, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Present Message Sent to " + item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach should be like this:

**1:** you have to save the checked state in your items in the listView. You probably fill the listView with a collection of Item objects. Suppose you have an adapter like this:

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CustomAdapter.Item> {
Context context;

public static class Item{
    boolean isChecked = false;
    public void setChecked(boolean checked) {this.isChecked = checked; }
    public boolean isChecked() {return this.isChecked;}
}

private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;

public CustomAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<Item> items) {
    super(context, resource, items);
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
    if (v == null) {
        LayoutInflater vi;
        vi = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        v = vi.inflate(R.layout.content_custom_list_view, null);
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                getItem(position).setChecked(isChecked);
            }
        });
    }
    return v;

}
```

}

Implement a logic in the checkbox listener so that each item object from yout listView saves its checked state. Then in the `SaveAndSend` method do this:

```
 ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.listView1);

      public void SaveAndSend(View view) {
        for (int i = 0; i < lv.getCount(); i++) {
            View v = lv.getAdapter().getView(i, null, null);
            if(((CustomAdapter.Item)lv.getAdapter().getItem(i)).isChecked()) {
                Toast.makeText(CustomListViewActivity.this, "checked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(CustomListViewActivity.this, "NOT checked!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }
```

I have tested it and it works just fine with your layouts.

Comment: The if condition does not correct while if i checked the checkbox. The code of else statement is always execute even i checked the checkbox.

Comment: I have edited my answer with a tested code. Try to implement it with your logic.